# Okta - Add User details to security context

Tags: spring-security, okta, okta-api

We are using micro-services as the middle ware and Angular 7 as our front end.
We are using Okta Angular SDK for authenticating the user and fetching the access token.
Angular will send the received token to Java where we are validating the user token.
Since authentication flow is handled by Angular, and from the token claims we are getting only limited user data ,I want to load the user object from data base and add it to the security context.

Please point me in the right direction to achieve this. Your help is much appreciated.
Tech stack - Spring boot -2.1.3 , Spring security 5,Angular 7.

Thanks.

Comment: You could stuff a bunch of claims with user information in your access token. However, a more secure way to do things would be to look up the user's information on the server using the access token and the `/userinfo` endpoint.

Comment: @MattRaible -- we are using organization level identity mgmt endpoints,so we cant do customization.And also, I think every time there is a service request, a call to /userinfo is not an ideal implementation

Answer (score 0):

I kind of used below config and got the loggedin user claim info in the security context now.

.YML

```
resource:
user-info-uri: https://dev-***.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/userinfo
```

dependency

```
spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure’, version: '2.0.0.RELEASE
```

Comment: This is not an answer but an another question on the top of the existing question. Please remove it. and ask your query in the comment section of the original question.